# Protecting Spreadsheet from renaming in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-sheets

I have Google Spreadsheet named "TeamWork" and I share it with about 50 other users, they can edit different ranges ad sheets. Problem is that when some of them want to change the name of file, they just can do it, so time to time I have funny names for this file, like "teamNotWork" etc.
Is there a way to prevent anyone except owner from rename Spreadheet? If possible not using "onEdit" script trigger, because its using quota.
Thanks for help!

Comment: I sent issue to Google Apps Script issues and feature requests:  Issue 6821: Spreadsheet name protection

Answer (score 1):

onOpen wont happen often enough and onEdit will consume too much quota.
instead, use a time based trigger (every minute or every 5 minutes) to rename the file if its not what you want.
it also has the advantage that it will work regardless of how users open the sheet (mobile or desktop).

Comment: So there's no way to set it up trigger-independent, it would be perfect to protect name via class method for example: SpreadSheet.name(string name, protected).

Comment: it is protected via script. You cant prevent the 1-minute delay because you already have quota issues if you use onEdit.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using onOpen trigger:

```
function onOpen() {
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  file.rename('TeamWork');
}
```

You may add one more [time Driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) and launch it once a day when nobody works with file.

Comment: It could help, but this file is being open for about 8 h a day, so if every user open it at 8:00 am and name is changed at 8:30 it would appear changed till next day. OnEdit script should do the work but I want to avoid that because i have already couple of them.

Comment: Does anyone care if file's name changed, till it's opened? You need name when you're trying to find the file by name, but there's a way to find it by direct link. `onOpen` also works when page is reloaded.

Comment: Supervisors care...:)